# How can I tell when my broccoli seeds are ready to harvest?

Tags: seeds, seed-saving, broccoli

How can I tell when the seed pods of broccoli (assuming thats what these little things are) are ready to be saved for next seasons planting?

*Sorry the picture is so blurry, my phone would not focus on the pods themselves. My finger in the bottom left of the picture is holding 1 up. You can also see them in the focused part in the top right.*

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the seeds are ready, the pods will turn brown and split, releasing the seeds all over the ground. To prevent that, you can cut the stems as soon as the first pods split, and hang them upside down indoors, with the ends covered in a paper bag. Then, when the pods split, the seeds will be released into the bag. Occasionally rubbing the pods helps remove the seeds.